# Time Machine converting .backupbundle files back to .sparsebundle for downgrading back from Catalina to Mohave

Tags: backup, time-machine, mojave, catalina, time-capsule

I'm one of the unlucky sods who accidentally updated wife's workstation to Catalina only to find out the hard way that her CS6 Suite won't really work. Long story short, got back to a fresh install of Mojave with all pre-Catalina updates.

When I'm trying to restore from a Time Machine backup the Migration Assistant won't connect. I narrowed down the reason to a pesky thing that Catalina does, which is when you back up with Time Machine on Catalina it changes the format of the backups without so much as notifying or asking you.

Apparently, there is a workaround to converting .backupbundle files back to .sparsebundle on Time Machine. Anyone know what that workaround entails?:)

Comment: I believe I got this to work with a simple extension rename in the past, but it might have been on Catalina (aka macOS just ignoring what the extension said)